# Sudoku solver Recurrence stack with try and fail technique

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, stack, sudoku

I am building a Sudoku solver that use the Try and Fail technique to solve any problem. My algorithm is:

1)Update (method that remove any possible value that already given as a final value to element in the same Row, column or squar)

2)Get the minimum element that has minimum number of possible values

3)start solve assuming the first possible value is the final value

4)save the current sate into a stack

5)Try to solve

5-a)If solved, return

5-b)if not solved and with invalid Sudoku, then Pop previous state

6)Repeat step 3) for all possible vaues (9)

7)Repeat step 2) until the puzzel is solved

This is my code

```
Stack<Element[][]> myStack= new Stack<>();
private Element[][] mySudoku;
public void solve(){
        update();//remove all final values from all possible values for each element
        if(isSudokuSolved(mySudoku)){
                return;
        }
        //find a cell that is not confirmed and has the minimal candidates
        int celli=-1,cellj=-1, p=10;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                if(mySudoku[i][j].getValue()==0){
                        if(mySudoku[i][j].getPossibleValues().size()<p){
                                celli=i;
                                cellj=j;
                                p=mySudoku[i][j].getPossibleValues().size();
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            for (int c = 0; c < mySudoku[celli][cellj].getPossibleValues().size() - 1; c++) {
                //save state  
                Element[][] copy=deepCopy(mySudoku);//copy the current state
                myStack.push(copy);
                //apply candidate to cell
                mySudoku[celli][cellj].setValue(mySudoku[celli][cellj].getPossibleValues().get(c));
                update();//check is solved
                if(checkValidInputSudoku(mySudoku)){
                    solve();
                }else{
                   try {
                        mySudoku = myStack.pop();
                    } catch (EmptyStackException est) {
                        //do nothing
                    } 
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        //if we have reached here then we are at the last possible value for the candidates so confirm candidate in cell
        if(celli!=-1 && cellj!=-1 && p!=10) {//Some problems happen here "out of Boundry -1 Error"
            mySudoku[celli][cellj].setValue(mySudoku[celli][cellj].getPossibleValues().get(mySudoku[celli][cellj].getPossibleValues().size()-1));
        }
}//end of solve method
```

I have spent more than 6 hours trying to find out the problem. I have checked for the Update() method, deepCopy() method and checkValidInputSudoku() method. They all works fine. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see one problem in your code. You have a loop that is sawing off the branch it sits on:

```
for(int c = 0; c < mySudoku[celli][cellj].getPossibleValues().size() - 1; c++) {
    ...
    mySudoku[celli][cellj].setValue(mySudoku[celli]cellj].getPossibleValues().get(c));
    ...
}
```

Apart from that, you are missing one of the values, it should be `for(c=0; c!=size; ++c)`, i.e. not `size - 1`. Also, calling getPossibleValues() just once would make this code much more readable. Lastly, catching and ignoring a stack underflow is just stupid, because it hides errors in your algorithm, as far as I can tell. If you don't know how to handle an error, don't just silence it. Since java requires you to catch it, put it in the outermost place possible or at least abort or do *something*, but don't ignore it!

One more thing: You are recursing and passing the context data via `mySodoku` and `myStack`. This is completely missing the point of recursion (or at least the way it's typically used), because the function call stack is the only stack you need. Using these to pass parameters only makes things more complicated than necessary. Instead, the function should return a partial sodoku puzzle and return either the fully solved puzzle or null. Using is easier to distinguish than the exception you're using now, and it's a regular and expected thing, not really exceptional. Then, when trying different choices, you set the cell to the values in turn and recurse, until the call doesn't return null. If none of the choices returns a solution, you clear the cell and return null yourself.

```
solve(sodoku):
    if sodoku is solved:
        return true
    if sodoku is invalid:
        return false

    c = some empty cell
    for v in 1...9:
        // set to a value and recurse
        c = v
        if solve(sodoku):
            // found a solution
            return true
    // no solution found, clear cell and return failure
    c = null
    return false
```

BTW: This strategy is called "backtracking". Using a cell with the least amount of possible values is called "pruning", which allows you to cut off whole branches from the search tree. Actually determining the possible values also helps avoiding a few futile attempts.

Comment: Thank you very very much for those advices., but i DON`T understand the need of "c=some empty cell", why should not I change in the whole puzzle "mySudoku" and return previous state in case of fail? What is the type od "res" and "soduko" that I will return?

Comment: should I give "res" an initial value?

Comment: The reason to null the cell is that the wrong value shouldn't remain in there. However, my assumption is that there is only a single sodoku ever, and that that is passed by reference between the functions. In that case, returning null for failure is silly, and it should be a boolean. I'll fix my pseudo-code.